# How i can set file location into a gst-launch command line?

Tags: gstreamer

i want to play an avi video with gst-launch command line . I tried the videotest command line :

gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! ximagesink

this command line work fine but if i want to play a video how i can set the file path? My video is located in opt directory.
I am new in gstreamer
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `playbin` element:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="file:///opt/myvideo.avi"
```

Comment: ok and if i want to set x ,y width and height of the video window , how i can do it? I play video on imx6 ull board with buildroot OS. Do you know a media player for this OS?